# fetch req object from res.sendFile()

Tags: node.js, express

I have this piece of code to open an Angular project served from NodeJS.

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.send(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
 });
```

How can I retrieve `req.headers.someField` from the above code.

Comment: The `app.use` just mounts the middleware. Unlike the `app.get` or `app.post` you can't get the headers inside the callback.

Comment: @DavidR can you please show it.

Comment: Check this out => http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.use